# Why does WebAssembly.instantiate() fail with invalid memory limits with a module properly working in Chrome?

Tags: node.js, webassembly

I have a tested WebAssembly module ( source : https://github.com/easychessanimations/cengine , working online demo : https://cengine.netlify.app ).

When I want to run the same module in Node.js with

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const buf = fs.readFileSync('./site/cengine.wasm');
(async function(){
    const lib = await WebAssembly.instantiate(new Uint8Array(buf)).then(res => res.instance.exports);
})()
```

I get

```
CompileError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): invalid memory limits flags @+1565
```

Searching on the error did not turn up any useful hint as to what is going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Node.js doesn't enable all the same wasm flags chrome does.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/wasm-check can show you which are currently enabled

List of flags you can pass to Node.js (see package for up-to-date list):

> **Reference types** (--experimental-wasm-anyref)
>
> **BigInt between js and wasm** (--experimental-wasm-bigint)
>
> **Bulk memory operations** (--experimental-wasm-bulk-memory)
>
> **Exceptions** (--experimental-wasm-eh)
>
> **Multi values** (--experimental-wasm-mv)
>
> **Tail recursion calls** (--experimental-wasm-return-call)
>
> **Saturated (non-trapping) conversions from float to int** (--experimental-wasm-sat-f2i-conversions)
>
> **Sign/zero extensions** (--experimental-wasm-se)
>
> **SIMD** (--experimental-wasm-simd)
>
> **Threads** (--experimental-wasm-threads)
>
> **Type reflection** (--experimental-wasm-type-reflection)